# Add external CSS file to blogger template

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger

In the HTML code of my blogger template I am trying to add an external link to a CSS file hosted in Google drive.

I have made the CSS file public and created a direct download link:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByXCg9N1QXp8ZWdEWHlIUjMyRDQ
```

What I did next is that from the blogger admin panel I selected the HTML code of my template using:

```
Theme -> Edit HTML
```

and in the `<head>` section I added the following line:

```
<link href='//drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByXCg9N1QXp8ZWdEWHlIUjMyRDQ' 
      rel='stylesheet' media='all' type='text/css'/>
```

When trying to do **Save Theme** I get the following error:

> Error parsing XML, line 9, column 53: The reference to entity "id"
>   must end with the ';' delimiter.

Apparently the XML parser of the theme code doesn't like the `href` attribute value. How can I rewrite the url so that it is accepted by the XML parser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the `&` symbol in the link. You will need to replace it with `&amp;` to make the link be accepted by Blogger's XML parser -

```
<link href='//drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=0ByXCg9N1QXp8ZWdEWHlIUjMyRDQ' 
  rel='stylesheet' media='all' type='text/css'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add an HTML widget and paste your code, it will automatically correct minor mistakes and search for the code in the theme file and move your code to the desired location in the file. After that, you can remove your widget.