# Blogger Conditional Tag using external CSS

Tags: css, conditional-statements, blogger

On my Blogger page there are  2 layouts - one for Home page and one for Single Item, and they are working fine. However, now I want to use remote css , without local XML file being used for everything.

But  it doesn't seem to be possible. The error I get is : A skin cannot contain the element: link. Only text and CDATA sections are accepted
Any ideas how to go about this?

```
<b:skin>
  <style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://user.github.io/folder/css/style_home.css" type="text/css"/>
  </style>
</b:skin>

<b:if cond='data:view.isSingleItem'>
  <style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://user.github.io/folder/css/style_blog.css" type="text/css"/>
  </style>
</b:if>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675506/add-external-css-file-to-blogger-template) can help you, have a look

Comment: I figured out solution for this problem:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://user.github.io/folder/css/style_home.css" type="text/css"/>

<b:skin></b:skin>

<b:if cond='data:view.isSingleItem'>
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://user.github.io/folder/css/style_blog.css" type="text/css"/>
  
</b:if>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<b:skin></b:skin>
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://user.github.io/folder/css/style_home.css" type="text/css"/>
<b:elseif cond='data:view.isSingleItem'/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://user.github.io/folder/css/style_blog.css" type="text/css"/>
</b:if>
```